# Pagespeed performance in Magento 2.3.6

Tags: magento2.3, layout, performance, pagespeed, criticalpathcss

I am trying to improve the performance of magento complying with the requirements of google page speed and I have come across this, I don't know if it is a bug, if I am missing something or what it is exactly.
The thing is, I have to add the critical inline css and defer the loading of the rest of the css to the bottom of the page.
I get to load the critical css inline using the native magento option.
[image]

The problem now comes when I use this option Magento by default copies the css that you have added in default_head_block.xml at the bottom of the page, but does not "delete" them from the header.
Moreover, the css files in the header add a preload tag,

[image]

I would like to know how they solved this, since I suppose it is a common problem in the rest of the websites.

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you need to take the CSS that you add to `critical.css` out of the 'normal' CSS/LESS files, as stated in the [docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-critical-path.html):

> Do not duplicate styles in critical.css and non-critical style sheets.

If you keep the styles in both you will end up with duplicated CSS.

Comment: Hi,
I know, but the problem is not that I have to eliminate the duplicate css, but how do I eliminate the minified and merged css files from the header, if using the critical css configuration it already puts them at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Do you have CSS merging enabled? I wonder if that conflicts with the critical CSS functionality

Comment: The only other idea I have is that both of those files are somehow critical, surely preload should only be added to the critical css files

Comment: If I have it activated, I do not know if that conflicts, I will try to deactivate it and see if it works as it should.

Comment: I have tried to disable the merge, but it does not solve the problem of removing / moving the files from the head, it adds "preload" to all the css. Any more ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the preloaded files to see what it contains, is it definitely the non-critical CSS?

Comment: bin/magento config:set dev/css/use_css_critical_path 1.  Make sure app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web/css/critical.css is where you have your css.  MInify your critical css but do not duplicate the css. Make sure that your template followed Magento standards when they were included.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a Magento bug. You can override **AsyncCssPlugin.php** for this. Check the below code and try to implement this code:

> Create File: `app/code/Fix/CriticalCss/registration.php`

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Fix_CriticalCss',
    __DIR__
);
```

> Create File: `app/code/Fix/CriticalCss/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Fix_CriticalCss" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> Create File: `app/code/Fix/CriticalCss/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Controller\Result\AsyncCssPlugin" type="Fix\CriticalCss\Controller\Result\AsyncCssPlugin" />
</config>
```

> Create File: `app/code/Fix/CriticalCss/Controller/Result/AsyncCssPlugin.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Fix\CriticalCss\Controller\Result;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http;

/**
 * Plugin for asynchronous CSS loading.
 */
class AsyncCssPlugin
{
    private const XML_PATH_USE_CSS_CRITICAL_PATH = 'dev/css/use_css_critical_path';

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
    {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Load CSS asynchronously if it is enabled in configuration.
     *
     * @param Http $subject
     * @return void
     */
    public function beforeSendResponse(Http $subject): void
    {
        $content = $subject->getContent();

        if (\is_string($content) && strpos($content, '</body') !== false && $this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            self::XML_PATH_USE_CSS_CRITICAL_PATH,
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        )) {
            $cssMatches = [];
            // add link rel preload to style sheets
            $content = preg_replace_callback(
                '@<link\b.*?rel=("|\')stylesheet\1.*?/>@',
                function ($matches) use (&$cssMatches) {
                    $cssMatches[] = $matches[0];
                    preg_match('@href=("|\')(.*?)\1@', $matches[0], $hrefAttribute);
                    $href = $hrefAttribute[2];
                    if (preg_match('@media=("|\')(.*?)\1@', $matches[0], $mediaAttribute)) {
                        $media = $mediaAttribute[2];
                    }
                    $media = $media ?? 'all';
                    $loadCssAsync = sprintf(
                        '<link rel="preload" as="style" media="%s" .
                         onload="this.onload=null;this.rel=\'stylesheet\'"' .
                        'href="%s">',
                        $media,
                        $href
                    );

                    //return $loadCssAsync;
                    return;
                },
                $content
            );

            if (!empty($cssMatches)) {
                $content = str_replace('</body', implode("\n", $cssMatches) . "\n</body", $content);
                $subject->setContent($content);
            }
        }
    }
}
```